# Why are these jquery events firing synchronously?

Tags: jquery

Given a number of '.hovertarget' divs on a page, the mouseover/mouseout events below seem to be firing synchronously - i.e. if you quickly move the mouse from one item (A) to another (B), the B fade-in will not start until the A fade-out has completed.  If you do this quickly you then have a sequence of fade-in/outs which play for a few seconds. **This is not the behaviour I want.  How do I change this so that the events are independent of one another?**

I'm using jquery 1.6.2

```
$(".hovertarget").live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    var child = $(event.target).find(".targetchild");
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
        child.fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        child.fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

HTML This applied to (as requested):

```
    <div class="hovertarget" id="s1"><div class="targetchild"></div></div>
    <div class="hovertarget" id="s2"><div class="targetchild"></div></div>
```

Comment: did you try to use **.stop()** method to stop animiation?

Comment: Have you tried to use fadeTo, also you should use delegate instead of live. It's an easy change $(".hovertarget").live to $(".hovertarget").delegate, should work the same. Also in this case, fadeTo would work better since it won't apply the display:none, otherwise you may get that jittering effect or some other unwanted effects.

Comment: @matt - no will try that. What is the difference between live and delegate? (I'm using live because these are dynamically added elements).

Comment: @UpTheCreek delegate is more efficient. They work the same in that it will add events after the DOM is loaded, but it will only scan a certain portion of the DOM. Actually looking at your code again, you would need to do something like `$(container).delegate(".hovertarget", ('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {...})`, but container can be body, you want to try to focus it down as much as possible. So if you have a parent container use that. So you can do `$("body").delegate`, which is still better than using live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to stop the previous animation if it wasn't completed yet.  Animations go in a queue unless you tell it to stop the current animation and clear the queue.  You can add the stop() command like this:

```
$(".hovertarget").live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    var child = $(event.target).find(".targetchild");
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
        child.stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        child.stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

See the [doc for .stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for more info on the parameters.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to be good enough for now.  It's not perfect for me though, becuase I don't want the 'fade-out' animation of div a to be canceled just because I start a fade-in on div B. I assumed that each dom object would have it's own queue - seems strange to me that they interfere with each other.  Thanks again.

Comment: They do each have their own separate queue.  You may be calling .stop() on more than you care to.  Show us your HTML and we might be able to offer some help on that.  Are you 100% sure that `child` is only ever a single object and not more than you intend?

Comment: Strange.  I've added the relevant HTML (extremely basic).  Since the child is being selected from the event.target node I don't see how I could be selecting more than one by mistake.  Let me extend the fade time to check that I'm not imagining things.

Comment: Yes - I was imagining the interaction :o  So thanks - this fixes it. The only thing that would make it perfect is if the fade in would start at the current opacity level, rather than jumping back to 0 - so that it fade-ins would look smoother when there was an unfinished fade-out.

Comment: change it to `.stop(true, false)` if you don't want it to jump to the end before starting the next animation.  A read of the doc page I referenced will help you.

Comment: You know, the whole logic you have here is a little odd to me.  Why not just use `.hover()` with two functions?

Comment: you're right - I'll read the link ;)   Agree hover() is more elegant - I think I originally did it this way becuase I didn't realise hover would accept two functions (or maybe it wasn't possible at the time). Also this way I can decide whether to use mouseout or mouseleave.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
child.stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
```

and

```
child.stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
```

Comment: I've just tried this and it does not seem to work - if you flick between the two it causes the events (or at least any animation) to stop firing completely.